# Including a dash(-) in an argument name in R

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create an a tag in Shiny with `data-toggle` as an argument. The call I'm making is

```
a(class = "dropdown-toggle", role = "button", id = "dropdownMenu", 
  data-toggle = "dropdown",
  ... # inner elements
)
```

The problem is that when R parsed the function call it interprets `data-toggle` as an expression and not an argument name so when it encounters the subsequent `=` I get the following parse error:

```
Error in parse: ... unexpected '=' ... data-toggle=
```

I found a workaround where I can assign the result of the call to `a` as a variable, and then add to its `attrib` list manually:

```
temp <- a(...)
temp$attribs[["data-toggle"]] <- "dropdown"
```

I was curious if there was a way to escape the name of `data-toggle` so I can do everything I need in the single call to `a()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just quote the attribute name.

```
a(class="a", "data-toggle"="b")
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize the answer was so simple :)